# Titles in two languages

Tags: titles

I need to add two titles in my paper one in my native language and another in english. Both of them will have subtitles with a longer caption, but the \maketitle should have only one author.

I don't know if this is something trivial or not, but the fact is that haven´t found any answers suitable to my problem.

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which document class will you use?

Comment: Welcome. The program doesn't really care about the language (concerning titles) maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: @gernot i'm using \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for you help but it won't work for me because of the document class I'm using.

Comment: @Johannes_B That is true, but typesetting *bilingual* titles is an ongoing headache, regardless of class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEEEtran` does not offer any facilities for subtitles and multilingual titles. However, you can put this information into the `\title` command like this.

```
\title{%
  Titulo do Artigo em Português\\
  {\Large Sub-título se necessarário em Português}\\[1ex]
  \itshape Paper Title in English\\
  {\Large Subtitle if needed in English}%
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\title{%
Titulo do Artigo em Português\\
  {\Large Sub-título se necessarário em Português}\\[1ex]
  \itshape Paper Title in English\\
  {\Large Subtitle if needed in English}%
}
\author{S.O.Mebody}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```